# What's the difference between a Sentinel value and an End-of-file character?

Tags: eof, sentinel, data-stream

This question stemmed from this (Software Development) textbook question:

> A value used to indicate the end of a data stream is called:
>
> 1. a sentinel value.
> 2. an end of file (EOF) character.
> 3. a flag.
> 4. a driver

The correct answer is apparently 1, though I answered 2.

I wasn't able to find a definition in the textbook of an end of file character though I did find the definition of a sentinel value.

> **Sentinel value** *(Textbook)*
>
> *A dummy value used to indicate the end of data within a file. Sentinel is from the word sentry, a sentry being a guard who prevents passage of unauthorised persons.*

However, this contradicts what I found on Wikipedia (sources seem legit).

> **Sentinel value** *[(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)*
>
> ... *a special value in the context of an algorithm which uses its presence as a condition of termination, typically in a loop or recursive algorithm*

Then the End-of-file definition.

> **End-of-file** *[(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)*
>
> ... *a condition in a computer operating system where no more data can be read from a data source. The data source is usually called a file or stream.*

So, from this, it seems the better (or correct?) answer is 2 since the question is asking about a "data stream". Does this mean the textbook definition is wrong or "dumbed down", or is an End-of-file character classed as a sentinel value?

Answer (score 0):

Typically in these Software textbooks, sentinel values are **usually** associated with file streams and the like.

If I remember correctly, chapters discussing sentinel values generally focused on file handling, so in this case, the answer would be 1.